# Find the earliest and latest time for each day based on a time range criteria in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two columns in Google Sheets:

B | C
Date | Time
2/21/2022 | 7:30:02 AM
2/21/2022 | 7:48:02 AM
2/21/2022 | 8:24:05 AM
2/21/2022 | 2:34:02 PM
2/21/2022 | 2:56:02 PM
2/22/2022 | 8:05:00 AM
2/22/2022 | 8:15:00 AM
2/22/2022 | 3:00:02 PM
2/22/2022 | 3:15:02 PM
2/22/2022 | 3:25:14 PM
etc...

[DateTimeData Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXi8E.png)

There are dozens of entries for Time in a single day. I would like to find the earliest Time and latest Time for each day within a Time range between (7:30:00 AM to 8:30:00 AM) AND (2:30:00 PM to 3:30:00 PM).
The result will be two Time values for each day.
i.e.

B | C
Date | Time
2/21/2022 | 7:48:02 AM
2/21/2022 | 2:56:02 PM
2/22/2022 | 8:05:00 AM
2/22/2022 | 3:15:02 PM
etc..

[GoalResult Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0r8f.png)

I was able to find the values of each day within the Time Range using this formula, but have not been able to extract the Lowest and Highest Time values for each day.

=ArrayFormula((IF(C2:C="","",IF((C2:C1000>VALUE(timevalue("7:30 AM")))*(C2:C1000<VALUE(timevalue("8:30 AM"))),C2:C1000,IF(C2:C="","",IF((C2:C1000>VALUE(timevalue("2:30 PM")))*(C2:C1000<VALUE(timevalue("3:30 PM"))),C2:C1000,0))))))

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Please supply a link to a spreadsheet with realistic sample data as a starting point, so that the volunteer contributors don't need to do that. Also, according to the sample data in your post, it seems the latest time for 2/22 between 2:30 and 3:30 would be 3:25:14, not 3:15:02.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=query(A:B,"select A,min(B),max(B) group by A  label max(B) 'End time' , min(B) 'Start time' ")
```

[image]

Comment: That is much easier than this one that someone else suggested. I formatted this for your example: =ArrayFormula(QUERY({SORT(A2:B,1,true,2,false),IFERROR(row(A2:A)-match(query(SORT(A2:B,1,true,2,false),"Select Col1"),query(SORT(A2:B,1,true,2,false),"Select Col1"),0))},"Select Col1,Col2 where Col3<2"))

Comment: How can I go about changing the Heading so that min time is Start Time and max time is End Time? - Thanks again!!

Comment: I have updated my answer